# Python return statement not returning correct output

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have a simple function to return True or False when a condition is met. But the return statement is not functioning as I expected. Could anyone help me out to point out the mistake I am making.

```
graph = {
'f': ['g', 'i'],
'g': ['h'],
'h': [],
'i': ['g', 'k'],
'j': ['i'],
'k': []
}

def hasPath(graph,source,des):
    arr = graph[source]
    if des in arr:
        print('Yes')
        return True
    for i in arr:
        hasPath(graph,i,des)
    return False

print(hasPath(graph,'f','k'))
```

This code return False but prints the statment Yes. I am not sure why return statement is not being executed after the Print statement.

Comment: You never use the return for anything, when it's True. False is the last iteration and the print gets executed when key i is getting checked. Try: `if hasPath(graph,i,des): return True` in your for loop.

Comment: Ohh okay. So that return statement after the Print statment only return the value to the place where I have called the function and not to return outside the function.

Comment: I am not sure why people have down voted this question. why are people so arrogant here. This was a genuine question with a genuine error. that's what this platform is all about.

Comment: Where you make the recursive calls `for i in arr: hasPath(graph,i,des)`, **what should happen** as a result? Are you trying to check whether **all** of those recursive calls give a `True` result? If **any** of them do? Something else? Regarding your complaint: being "genuine" is not enough to make a question useful and on topic for the site - nowhere near.

Comment: So you consider "Import error" as error as the genuine questions. Great Thinking. Anyway I already Got the answer for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `hasPath` function, you are calling the function recursively on each element in the `arr` list, and the return value of the recursive calls is not being used. This means that even if the `des` value is present in the `arr` list and the `print` statement is executed, the `return False` statement at the end of the function will still be executed and the `False` value will be returned.

To fix this issue, you can add a return statement after the recursive call to `hasPath` to return the value of the recursive call. This will ensure that the `return True` statement is executed when the des value is found in the `arr` list, and the return False statement at the end of the function will not be executed.

Here is an example of how you can modify the `hasPath` function to fix this issue:

```
def hasPath(graph, source, des):
    arr = graph[source]
    if des in arr:
        print('Yes')
        return True
    for i in arr:
        if hasPath(graph, i, des):
            return True
    return False
```

With this change, the `hasPath` function will return True when the `des` value is found in the `arr` list, and will return `False` otherwise. When you run the `print(hasPath(graph, 'f', 'k'))` statement, it will print `Yes` and then `True`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
graph = {
'f': ['g', 'i'],
'g': ['h'],
'h': [],
'i': ['g', 'k'],
'j': ['i'],
'k': []
}

def hasPath(graph,source,des):
    arr = graph[source]
    if des in arr:
        print('Yes')
        return True
    for i in arr:
        if hasPath(graph,i,des): return True
    return False

print(hasPath(graph,'f','k'))
```

Result:

```
Yes
True
```

Why?

Well try to look at each iteration:

1. source is f, arr = ['g', 'i'] = False
2. source changes to i = g, now arr = ['h'] = False
3. source changes to h which is empty and returns False
4. First iteration changes to i in graph[f] and it starts again
5. Source changes to g in key i = False
6. source changes to k in key i = True